# Buscar primera coincidencia de un elemento cualquiera de un array en un texto

Tags: javascript, array, string

Pongamos que se dispone de una variable *array* con x elementos, todos ellos string y que, por otro lado, se tiene una variable *input* (también string) dentro de la cual puede o no haber alguno o varios de los elementos del array.

Cómo podría determinar cuál es el primer elemento de la variable que coincide con uno cualquiera del array? Le he dado vueltas y vueltas y no consigo encontrar la manera.

Ejemplo:

```
array = ['seno', 'coseno', 'tangente', 'raiz cuadrada', 'logaritmo']
input = 'raiz cuadrada del coseno de 30'
```

Querría una función que me devolviese "raiz cuadrada", ya que es el primer elemento de *input* que coincide con cualquiera de *array*

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let array = ['seno', 'coseno', 'tangente', 'raiz cuadrada', 'logaritmo'];
    // Esto lo que hace es convertirte el String en un array dividido por los espacios de la cadena.
    let input = 'raiz cuadrada del coseno de 30'.split(" ");

    for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        // Esto lo que hace es obtener la palabra i del array (input)
        let actual = input[i];
        // Aquí comprobamos que exista la palabra en el array, ya que si no existe, devuevlve -1
        if(array.indexOf(actual) != -1) {
            console.log("Palabra encontrada en la posición " + array.indexOf(actual) + " de la lista");
            console.log("La palabra es: " + actual); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tu función no devuelve "raiz cuadrada" porque solo reconoce palabras separadas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `indexOf` de `input` para conocer el índice de la posición inicial del `string`. Creo que no es posible obtener un índice de la palabra cuando tienes más palabras que una en tu `array`.

```js
const array = ["seno", "coseno", "tangente", "raiz cuadrada", "logaritmo"];
const input = "raiz cuadrada del coseno de 30";

const lista = array.map(texto => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`\\b(${texto})\\b`, 'g');
  const match = input.match(regex);
  if (match !== null) {
    const index = input.indexOf(match);
    return { index: index, texto: texto };
  }
}).filter(filter => filter !== undefined);

console.log(lista);
```